# Command Handler - Discord Welcome Embed

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to get my Embed to load on `guildmemberAdd`. This is my code below, as this is all a learning curve. I could really use come help correcting my mistake, so that when my new guild member joins, my Embed pops up automatically.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'NewMember')
        
    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole)
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('My discord channel').send(` <@${guildMember.user.id}> `)
    member.guild.channels.get('My discord channel').send('reactionrole'); 
});
```

Comment: Does a normal message send when a user joins? From your question are you asking how to send an embed or what?

Comment: I'm wanting my Embed to load on new member joining server, they are prompted to choose their roles and my embed has vital info. 

I'm looking for the correct command handler to execute this, at the moment  I need to execute this command by;

 if (command === 'reactionrole') {
            client.commands.get('reactionrole').execute(message, args, Discord, client);  I have to execute this directly in discord by entering "-reactionrole"

Comment: @Zsolt Meszaros Thank you for the edit, I am met with and error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\greg\Desktop\Welcome\discord.js:24:63)
    at Client.emit (node:events:379:20)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed 2 issues within one particular line of your code:

#### `member` is not defined

You seem to look for a channel based off a member object - Which by itself is completely fine, but you have never defined the variable `member` itself. This can be found in the last line of your code, stating:

```
    member.guild.channels.get('My discord channel').send('reactionrole');
```

The simple fix to this is replacing `member` with `guildMember`, as it is how you defined the GuildMember object of the user who just joined your guild.

#### Lacking `.cache`

In the same line, you seem to want to find a channel based off a guild's channels list. In the not so recent discord.js update, also known as v12, you are now required to use the `.cache` method to receive a full Collection of an entire guild's **cached** channels list, unless you fetch them instead.

#### Final Code

````
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'NewMember')
        
    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole)
    /** 
    * Keep in mind neither of the below methods send an Embed. 
    * You would need to create a MessageEmbed Constructor to do so.
    */
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('My discord channel').send(` <@${guildMember.user.id}> `)
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('My discord channel').send('reactionrole'); 
});```
````

Comment: Good morning @Bqre, thank you for getting back to me. As this is entirely a learning curve for me and something I'm quickly enjoying more and more. Every peace of help i get is a huge help on how to make things better, and I'm grateful to all. 

Currently I'm getting an error on TypeError: guildMember.guild.channels.cache.fetch is not a function

Code below; 
discord.js
https://pastebin.com/AQBVBab8
reactionrole.js
https://pastebin.com/TeVGJWUQ


Would you be able to take a look at my reactionrol.js & discord.js files,

Comment: You're not required to use the `.cache` method while fetching. `guildMember.guild.channels.fetch('...')`

Comment: Using the .fetch function - I receive TypeError: guildMember.guild.channels.fetch is not a function